# Updating speedometer data from json object created with PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts, dotnethighcharts, gwt-highcharts

Can someone tell me how to update the data into speedometer highchart from the Json object created using php script, Its working for bar charts and pie chart but i can't figure it out for the speedometer , The data formats is perfectly matching but i don't know how to update the data into the  speedometer.js file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get json, call [point.update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update) and chart will be redrawn.